# How can an installed app redirect users to the app store for installation when the application is not yet installed?

Tags: android, frontend

I want to know how to implement a prompt for redirection or direct redirection to the app store.

Do I need to redirect to a web page for it to determine whether the app is installed?

Or do I just need to include certain data in the app?